# RecyclerView didn't show my expected output

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I want data from firebase to be printed out in recyclerview list.
The loop is correct but, it didn't replace my data.

This is from the track_record code.

```
 private void readData(){

    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("FireAlarm");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            dataList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Data data = snapshot.getValue(Data.class);
                    dataList.add(data);
            }
            recordAdapter = new RecordAdapter(track_record.this,dataList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(recordAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

this is from my adapter

```
@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_data,parent,false);
    return new RecordAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Data data = dataList.get(position);
    holder.outputData.setText(data.getAlarm());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView outputData;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);

        outputData = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dataFetch);
    }
}
```

this is from xml the data should be replaced

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/dataFetch"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="data"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:background="#F5B6B6"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>
```

this is my database

[image: my database look like this]

this is current output
[image: this is the current output]

Comment: Use tag android. Please don't tag questions with IDE tags (android-studio), just because you use that IDE: these tags should only be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags), and the [tagging guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging). Also, please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: post your full code of adapter.

Comment: add code of data class

Comment: `FireAlarm` is your root node? Please responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: yes FireAlarm is my root node @AlexMamo

Comment: @Izz Have you tried to change `reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("FireAlarm")` to `reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()`? Does it work this way?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `addChildEventListener` instead of `addValueEventListener`, and write the code inside `onChildAdded`.

You can find the explanation from [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data):

> When working with lists, your application should listen for child
>   events rather than the value events used for single objects.

Answer (score 0):

You must add child value event listener to `FireAlarm`, the listener will be triggered as soon as it is attached to a DatabaseReference object (in your code the object is `reference`) by calling `onChildAdded()` method and triggered each time data in the child added, removed, changed,...
Your `readData` should be rewritten as below:

```
reference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                Data data = (Data) dataSnapshot.getValue(Data.class);
                dataList.add(data);
                //then notify data changed 
                recordAdapter.notifyDataSetChange();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

               Data data = (Data) dataSnapshot.getValue(Data.class);
                //then find position of `data` in datalist to change some information of the item at position.
                //then notify data changed 
                recordAdapter.notifyDataSetChange(); 
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Data data = (Data) dataSnapshot.getValue(Data.class);
                //then find data in datalist to remove, after removed, notify data set changed
                recordAdapter.notifyDataSetChange();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```